# How to setup MPI on Qt on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, mpi

I'm having real trouble setting up MPI with and existing Qt project.
I've added the openMPI include and lib directories to the .pro file, but I'm not sure what else to do to get it running.

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

(edit)

my includepath in the .pro file:

```
    INCLUDEPATH+=C:\\opencv\\build\\install\\include \
       C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\include\
```

Comment: Can you explain what error you're getting?

Comment: "cannot open include file 'mpi.h': no such file or directory
but the mpi.h file is in the include directory

Comment: You've added the path to the INCLUDEPATH in the .pro file?

Comment: You should probably escape backslashes and spaces in the path to Open MPI's `include` directory with backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wasn't running qmake (under build->run qmake)
so all the .pro edits weren't being recognised!
thanks for your help anyway!